# Create multiple records with one form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 3 models: User, Ingredient, and a map of which user has which ingredients - UserIngredient.

My current setup works for adding 1 ingredient at a time. What I want is to update the code so that users can enter a few ingredients and just click "submit" once rather than clicking it for each ingredient individually. I've looked into nested_resources but it seems like not the right place to use it.

What is the right way of doing this?

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  has_many :user_ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :user_ingredients
  
  ...
end
```

app/models/ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  has_many :user_ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :owners, through: :user_ingredients

  ...
end
```

app/models/user_ingredient.rb

```
class UserIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ingredient

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :ingredient, presence: true
end
```

app/views/user_ingredients/new.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= turbo_frame_tag @user_ingredient do %>
    <%= render "form", user_ingredient: @user_ingredient %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

app/views/user_ingredients/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="w-full mx-auto">
  <%= form_for @user_ingredient do |f| %>
    <div class="flex-row gap--md">
      <%= f.select(
        :ingredient_id,
        options_from_collection_for_select(Ingredient.where(id: f.object.ingredient_id), :id, :name, :selected => f.object.ingredient_id),
        { prompt: 'Start typing to search' },
        { id: "drDwn_ingredient",
          class: "w-full border border-black",
          required: true,
          data: { 
            controller: "selectIngredient",
            selectIngredient_url_value: autocomplete_ingredients_path,
          },
        }) %>

      <div class="flex-row gap--xxxs">
        <label>
          <input type="submit" class="add_cancel_ing gap--md" />
          <%= inline_svg_tag "svg/circle-check.svg", class: "svg_add_ing" %>
        </label>
        <%= link_to user_ingredients_path do %>
          <%= inline_svg_tag "svg/circle-xmark.svg", class: 'svg_cancel_ing' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

app/controllers/user_ingredients_controller.rb

```
class UserIngredientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user_ingredient, only: [:show, :destroy]

  def index
    @user_ingredients = current_user.user_ingredients
  end

  def new
    @user_ingredient = UserIngredient.new
  end

  def create
    @user_ingredient = UserIngredient.new(user_ingredient_params.merge(user: current_user))

    if @user_ingredient.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to user_ingredients_path, notice: 'Ingredient was successfully added to your bar!' }
        format.turbo_stream { flash.now[:notice] = 'Ingredient was successfully added to your bar!' }
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user_ingredient.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_ingredients_path, notice: "Ingredient was removed!" }
      format.turbo_stream { flash.now[:notice] = "Ingredient was removed!" }
    end
  end

  private

  ...

  def set_user_ingredient
    @user_ingredient = current_user.user_ingredients.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_ingredient_params
    params.require(:user_ingredient).permit(:id, :ingredient_id)
  end
end
```

app/javascript/controllers/selectIngredient_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import { get } from "@rails/request.js";
import TomSelect from "tom-select";

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { url: String };

  multi_select_config = function () {
    return {
      plugins: ["remove_button", "no_active_items"],
      valueField: "value",
      load: (q, callback) => this.search(q, callback),

      closeAfterSelect: true,
      persist: false,
      create: false,
    };
  };

  async search(q, callback) {
    const response = await get(this.urlValue, {
      query: { q: q },
      responseKind: "json",
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const list = await response.json;
      callback(list);
    } else {
      console.log("Error in select_ctrl: ");
      console.log(response);
      callback();
    }
  }

  connect() {
    new TomSelect(this.element, this.multi_select_config());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method for `User`
And try to create related records via `User`.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Or you can try to make custom action for accepting custom form with multiple records at once. But first option will be more predictable and easier for supporting.

For views you can use `cocoon` gem. It's pretty old, but it still works good.
Or you can inspire by it and make your custom solution)
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon